# Which is the correct preposition: ... draws on research and analysis [from/by] leading experts ...?

Tags: prepositions

I wrote the following sentence, but I can't figure out which is the appropriate preposition in this case.

> This paper draws on research and analysis **from** some of Canada’s leading experts on UI.

#### Is it "from" or "by"?

Here are some examples from google books and google news:

**"draws on research from"**

1. This area of disaster social work research, as might be expected, draws on research **from** a number of disciplines including psychology, sociology, and geography.
2. The chapter draws on research **from** multiple disciplines that examine the psychological, social, and environmental factors that affect ...
3. It draws on research **from** economics, law, demography, sociology, and other disciplines.
4. LSE IQ is a monthly podcast that draws on research **from** the social sciences.

**"draws on research by"**

5. This chapter draws on research **by** Martin Minogue, David Levi-Faur and Malathy Knight-John on the politics of regulation.
6. Chapter 6 draws on research **by** Bernard Hoekman, Constantine Michalopoulos, and L. Alan Winters.
7. This section ... draws on research **by** Oswald et al. (2016), Tyler (2015) and Van der Bom et al. (2018) ...
8. Piketty was among the founders of the WID, which draws on research **by** more than 100 economists globally.
9. Their work draws on research **by** Timothy Besley and Torsten Persson.

**Here is what I think based on the above examples:**

> It seems like "from" is used when talking about specific disciplines, fields of study, organizations, and other sources. And the preposition "by" is used when talking about people. Is this correct? Because there are examples that do not follow this pattern.

10. The campaign draws on research **by** the **Brookings Institution and the Information Technology and Innovation Foundation.** - Wall Street Journal
11. The full study, which draws on research **by the World Bank**, was published in the Journal of Development Economics (JDE).

#### What is the consensus on this?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, both can be used interchangeably. I would personally use *draws on research by* when talking about specific people as you stated:

> Their work draws on research by Timothy Besley and Torsten Persson.

*Draws on research from* is more general instead of mentioning specific people or organisations.